# Sum only third element for two tables of data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have

```
J = Table[{x10, y10, x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}]
L = Table[{x10, y10, 2.0*x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}]
```

I want the third elements of J and L to be added and the first and second elements are as they are (as they are the same in both cases) for an example.

Comment: Never use upper-case letters, or strings with an initial upper-case letter to name a variable in *Mathematica* as it can conflict with internal names.

Answer (score 8):

```
result = J;
result[[All, All, 3]] += L[[All, All, 3]]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
tJ = Table[{x10, y10, x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];
tL = Table[{x10, y10, 2.0*x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];
```

Several alternatives:

```
tK1 = Map[{0, 0, 1} # &, tJ, {-2}] + tL;
tK2 = MapAt[2 # &, Mean[{tJ, tL}], {{All, All, -1}}];
tK3 = Mean[{tJ, tL}]; tK2[[All, All, -1]] = 2 tK2[[All, All, -1]];

Grid[tK1, Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \{0.,0.,0.\} & \{0.,0.5,0.\} & \{0.,1.,0.\} \\
> \hline
>  \{0.5,0.,0.\} & \{0.5,0.5,0.75\} & \{0.5,1.,1.5\} \\
> \hline
>  \{1.,0.,0.\} & \{1.,0.5,1.5\} & \{1.,1.,3.\} \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

```
tK1 == tK2 == tK3
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]] + #2[[3]]} &, {J, L}, 2]
```

do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility

```
t3 = Map[(# /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {0, 0, c}) &, t1, {2}] + t2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
j = Table[{x10, y10, x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];
l = Table[{x10, y10, 2.0*x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];

Partition[
 Transpose[{Partition[Flatten[j], 3], Partition[Flatten[l], 3]}] /. 
  {{x1_, y1_, r1_}, {x2_, y2_, r2_}} :> {x1, y1, r1 + r2}
, 3]

{{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.5, 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}}, 
 {{0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.75}, {0.5, 1., 1.5}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0.5, 1.5}, {1., 1., 3.}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Table[{x10, y10, x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];

b = Table[{x10, y10, 2.0*x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];
```

If we replace the 1st and 2nd elements of `b` with `0`, it's a simple
addition

```
a + MapAt[0 &, b, {;; , ;; , ;; 2}
```

returns

```
{{{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.5, 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}}, 
 {{0.5, 0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.75}, {0.5, 1., 1.5}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0.5, 1.5}, {1., 1., 3.}}}
```

We get the same result with

```
a + Replace[b, {__, x_} :> {0, 0, x}, {2}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tJ = Table[{x10, y10, x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];

tL = Table[{x10, y10, 2.0*x10*y10}, {x10, 0, 1, 0.5}, {y10, 0, 1, 0.5}];
```

We can also use new-in-Version-13.1 [`Threaded`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html):

```
tK = tL + Threaded[{0, 0, 1}] tJ;


Column[Labeled[
     Grid[ToExpression @ #, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {10, 1}], #, Left] & /@ 
  {"tL", "tJ", "tK"}]
```

[image]